# Как организовать разработку Python приложения? (debug / release)

Tags: python

**Разрабатываю Discord бота.**
Перед запуском релиза на основном клиенте, тестирую его на другом боте на специальном тестовом сервере.

Когда некое состояние кода (когда был дописан новый функционал/профикшены баги, всё протестировано) можно считать за релиз, он благополучно запускается через командную строку.

Дальше, образуется вот такая дилемма: если продолжить писать код в папке с проектом, то запустить релиз я не смогу из-за некоторых изменённых файлов, в которых не факт что я всё не поломал.

Достаточно продолжительное время в папке проекта у меня была папка `dev`, в которой я писал код, и когда я заканчивал, копировал из него файлы в корень проекта и запускал приложение. И это реально решало проблему. Я имел возможность запускать код в разработке на одном клиенте и одновременно запускать стабильный релиз когда мне вздумается.

Со временем начала бесить фактически полная идентичность корня проекта и папки `dev`.

В условном C++, в ещё более условной папке `bin`, есть 2 подкаталога: `debug` и `release`. Скомпилировав проект в `release`, я всегда его могу оттуда запускать, а смотреть как работает новый код можно через .exe в `debug` - для меня это является сверхудобной штукой.

Недавно я обнаружил для себя Docker. Примерная идея - заворачивать релиз в контейнер и хранить в отдельной папке в удобном формате (+ к стабильности за счёт упаковки зависимостей).

**Правильно ли я думаю? Может можно проще? Как обеспечить удобное "переключение" между пишущимся и стабильным кодом?**

Comment: Git  пора начать учить. Ветки...

Comment: @eri Я им активно пользуюсь. Я так понимаю, идея в том, чтобы подгружать в папку код из последнего коммита из нужной ветки?

Comment: Идея что у вас будут все равно будут 2 папки. Но файлы не копируете, а сливаете с одной ветки на другую

Comment: Спасибо! Возможно совмещу Docker с механикой веток.